# Revolution slider extract function on each slide

Tags: jquery, revolution-slider

I'm use 4.5.3 (11.06.2013) Ver of jQuery Revolution slider (Not wordpress) and i want to extract js function on each slide end...

Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The event you are looking for is revolution.slide.onbeforeswap  and you can listen on it like:

```
jQuery('#yoursliderid').bind('revolution.slide.onbeforeswap',function() {
  // your functions here 
});
```

For further informations about all available methods and events check out the Documentation you get by purchasing the product.   Also more info available here:
http://themepunch.com/support-center